# AppArmor is causing Firefox segfaults

Tags: linux, debian, debugging, apparmor

I realise this is probably a bad question but I'm stuck. After a lot of googling I'm struggling to fix the problem. I've been trying to get AppArmor to work on Debian. I've been following the instructions from https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse.

Part of the instruction told me to do

```
sudo perl -pi -e 's,GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="(.*)"$,GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="$1 apparmor=1 security=apparmor",' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Because I didn't understand the `perl` command I did this in my VM and now I can't use Firefox, not even in safemode. I get a segfault.

```
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

(firefox:3875): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='common'
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1]: no fonts - init: 1 fonts: 0 loader: 0 (t=0.206719) [GFX1]: no fonts - init: 1 fonts: 0 loader: 0
[3875] ###!!! ABORT: unable to find a usable font (Sans): file /tmp/buildd/firefox-47.0.1/gfx/thebes/gfxTextRun.cpp, line 1875
[3875] ###!!! ABORT: unable to find a usable font (Sans): file /tmp/buildd/firefox-47.0.1/gfx/thebes/gfxTextRun.cpp, line 1875
Segmentation fault

apt-cache policy apparmor

apparmor:
  Installed: 2.9.0-3
  Candidate: 2.9.0-3
  Version table:
     2.10.95-4~bpo8+2 0
        100 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.9.0-3 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

ls -l on /etc/fonts/fonts.conf returns the following:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5533 Nov 23 2014 /etc/fonts/fonts.conf
```

I tried exporting the font config path with the command

```
export FONTCONFIG_PATH=/etc/fonts
```

however this didn't help.

I know this is looking for a font that doesn't exist because I checked the path but now I'm at an impasse, out of ideas and can't find anymore help from Google.

Comment: I assume you are asking for the output? I've added it to the question. In future could you be more specific please?

Comment: `export FONTCONFIG_PATH=/etc/fonts` and then in the same terminal `firefox`

Comment: and please post `ls -l /etc/fonts/fonts.conf`

Comment: have you rebooted since the grub update?

Comment: to be more specific, of course, well, ok, `export` will give temporary instruction where to look for default fonts and `ls -l` will tell me if the config file even exists and what user rights it has

Comment: `apt-cache policy firefox`

Comment: I'm off, let's continue tomorrow - if not solved already

Comment: You need to give us result of `ls -l` so we know what kind of permissions the file has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue. The way I did this was by editing /etc/default/grub and changing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" apparmor=1 security=apparmor"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then after running `sudo update grub` and `sudo reboot` the issue was fixed. However this stopped apparmor from working as it gave the error:

`apparmor.common.AppArmorException: 'Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?\nUse --subdomainfs to override.\n'`

However I managed to solve this by using the commands from the debian guide again.

```
sudo perl -pi -e 's,GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="(.*)"$,GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="$1 apparmor=1 security=apparmor",' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

After the reboot I tried to launch firefox and I didn't get any errors and it is all working fine now. However after trying it on my pc I started having the segfault issue again and this fix didn't work. but after comparing the apparmor profiles in `/etc/apparmor.d` I found that the profile rules were different.

Rules on segfaulting pc:

```
# Last Modified: Tue Aug  2 11:32:25 2016
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/lib/firefox/firefox {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  /usr/bin/firefox r,

}
```

Rules on working pc:

```
# Last Modified: Tue Aug  2 11:32:25 2016
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/firefox {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/bash>

  /bin/dash ix,
  /usr/bin/firefox r,

}
```

I added `#include <abstractions/bash>` and `/bin/dash ix,` to the config file, then changed the path to `/usr/bin/firefox` and now the issue is fixed after rebooting.

Comment: This isn't a good solution because it's literally "my key is sticking in the lock, so I crashed my truck through the wall in the side of the house". You disabled ALL AppArmor security, when probably a single line added to /etc/apparmor.d/local/user.bin/firefox would suffice. (I just don't know what that line is yet.)